# Identity Server 3 Redirect to login page after logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I've successfully been able to implement this using http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2015-01-11-auto-redirect-when-logging-out.html

But!

I'd like to be able to display a message similar to "You've been successfully logged out" once redirected back to login screen.

I've tried setting a session value in my logoff action method prior to going over to the sign in page... but then the session is still null in the LogonWorkflow --> Login.cshtml razor view.

Any suggestions? Help!

Comment: Do you have the ability to specify a separate page for redirect to login and redirect after logout?

Comment: "Separate page for redirect to login" - No

"Redirect after logout" .... I'm achieving that with aaron powell's post listed above